# SQL query is running 10 times faster on local desktop SQL Server Express than on SQL Server in Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, azure

We are currently running two instances of SQL Server. For development purposes, we run a local DB on a desktop PC in our office.

The PC has following stats:

- 8 GB Ram
- AMD Athlon 5350 APU with Radeon(tm) R3 2.05 GZ
- 64 Bit Windows 8.1
- Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) Express Edition (64-bit)
- HDD Seagate ST1000DM003 1 TB

The server is located in Azure as VM Standard-Tier A3 running the pre-provided Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter image

Now we are facing a problem that the exact same query is running locally on the desktop 10 times faster than the on the server.

I connect to the pc with a local installed Management Studio via TCP/IP over our local network. When I connect to the server I use Remote Desktop connection and start a local instance of management studio on the server.

I have changed already the connection mode from default to TCP/IP on the server which brings me to the factor 10 times slower with default connection it will be 20 times slower. Even changing to named pipes the performance is worse.

Also rewriting the query and using different approaches, always the express version is much faster than the server. We did not do any configuration or tuning on the installation of the express version so on the server side.

Any comments a very appreciated!

Best
Simon

Comment: Have you looked at actual execution plans? Are they the same?

Comment: Are you sure it is really the QUERY, and not the time needed to transfer the result from the server to the client? Have you checked run time and execution plans of the query? In SQL Managament Studio, use Menu "Query" ->  "Include Actual Execution Plan" and "Include Client Statistics". Then run your query, and have a look.

Comment: @GeorgScholz If I'm not mistaken the OP stated that they're executing the query by logging onto the server via RDP and running SSMS on the server. This means the client and server are on the same machine in each case.

Comment: @IanNewson ah yes, right, Well, I would look first on the performance results. Also, it should be noted that the Azure servers are virtual machines. I don't know how they are actually implemented, but it might be that multiple serves are sharing one physical CPU.

Comment: Yes the ssms is running locally on the server. Also the script is not transfering results back to the client execpt the status like "1 row affected". basically we have created a stored procedure, which pulls data from tables, split strings and write the result in a table. in the procedure we create indexes to speed up the work. there is no data transfer like a classic select statement.

Comment: Check execution plan as @Igor suggested, may be you lack statistics and the plan is different. Or for some reason the same query is executed in strange manner.

Comment: First: This question belongs on ServerFault, not StackOverflow (it's not a programming question). Second: Aside from listing the VM cores/RAM details, you should including the VM size tier (e.g. A8). And... you've said nothing about the database itself (such as its size or where it's stored), nor the query. How big is the db? Where is it stored in Azure (e.g. regular blob-backed VHD? SSD-backed VHD)? Non-SSD vs SSD could make a big difference. You should edit your question with this info.

Comment: And while I still think this belongs on ServerFault: If it turns out to be a SQL query question, then it definitely stays here on StackOverflow (but so far it sounds like an infrastructure issue).

Comment: @DavidMakogon If the execution plans are different, then I'd consider it to be related to programming and database design. If the plans are equal, then I would relate it to a server issue.

Comment: Yes I have checked the plans right now. The plans are equal byside the estimation of the costs. So I think as well this could be an server issue or maybe an configuration issue. is there somewhere a quick howto or checklist for performance improvement on MS-SQL server?

Comment: @DavidMakogon I made an edit for the Azure tier details.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Local machine have SSD ? If it's the case, it's normal.

Try to rebuild indexes used.

**Update the Database/Table statistics.** The Execution Plan can be the same, but with bad stats, **I've often saw very low performance**. Especially if you make a lot of insert/delete.

You can see if something is wrong with SET STATISTICS IO ON. Look at the logical reads on tables, the orders of workfill tables, etc. Check if it's different from the local server.

Comment: we just have one Seagate ST1000DM003 1 TB, Disk in the PC. During the procedure we drop and recreate the indexes for every execution to avoid fragmentation. the costs are minimal and we go along with that. I have now updated the table stats and there were system indexes on this tables which needed update. Currently the script is running for 5000 jobs and I will let it finish, since we need the data online. I will come back to you on this an answer on Monday.

Comment: This answer fits better as a comment, since it's asking more questions (and we still don't have a root cause). And the follow-on info in the comment? It shouldn't be buried here. It should be an edit to the original question.

Comment: Sorry. I edited my post, so it's more a reponse than a comment now (i'm not very used to stackoverflow) ?

The root cause is, in my opinion, the stats...

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following at the top of the query to see where the differences are:

SET STATISTICS TIME ON

SET STATISTICS IO ON

Comment: This isn't an answer. This is a way to help determine the answer. Ergo, comment on the question.